# Trying to validate user input in java

Tags: java, user-input, do-while

Sorry guys, first time poster here, so please let me know if there's some etiquette or anything I should be following!

I've seen a few of these on the forums, and I've scoured through them, trying to make one work, but I can't seem to do it.

I need to create a program that asks for the user to input two positive integers. Each time an integer is answered, I want to validate to make sure it is 1) a number and 2) also positive. If it is not, I am supposed to just terminate the program. So far, I've tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4 {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter two positive integers.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the first integer:");
        int num1 = in.nextInt();
    do {
        System.out.println("Invalid. ***End of Program***");
        System.exit(0);
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid. ***End of Program***");
            System.exit(0);
                    }
        }while (num1 <= 0);
        }
    }
}
```

which works for when I enter a negative number, but for some reason, java just receives the invalid error input and doesn't run when I type in a letter. I also tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4 {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter two positive integers.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the first integer:");
        int num1 = in.nextInt()
        if (!in.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Invalid integer. ***End of Program***");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if (num1 <= 0){
            System.out.println("Invalid negative number. ***End of Program***");
            System.exit(0);
}
}
}
```

which just doesn't do anything. I've been at this problem for about 2 hours yesterday and another hour today, looking online for other solutions. I cannot use any match or try/catch statements, as I have not learned them yet! Any insight would be great, as I'm going crazy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're attempting to read in whatever the user inputs as an `int` value.

If the input happens to be something other than an integer, the program will return an `InputMismatchException`.

To handle this we would do the following:

```
int num1, num2 = 0;

try {
    System.out.println("Please enter two positive integers.");
    System.out.println("Please enter the first integer:");
    num1 = in.nextInt();

    if(num1 < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid integer. ***End of Program***");
        System.exit(0);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter the second integer:");
        num2 = in.nextInt();

        if(num2 < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid integer. ***End of Program***");
            System.exit(0);
        }
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("That is not an integer. ***End of Program***");
    System.exit(0);
}
...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `InputMismatchException` when capturing an integer using `nextInt()`.

```
    int num1 = 0;
    try {
       num1 = in.nextInt()
       if(num1 < 0) {
         System.out.println(num1 + " is not a positive integer");
       }
    } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
        System.out.println(num1 + " is not a valid integer");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of typing letter you are getting error because you read the text by using in.nextInt().

Try to place your code under try/catch block-

```
try{
     int num1 = in.nextInt();
     if (!in.hasNextInt())
     {
         System.out.println("Invalid integer. ***End of Program***");
         System.exit(0);
     }else if (num1 <= 0){
         System.out.println("Invalid negative number. ***End of Program***");
         System.exit(0);
     }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
         System.out.println(" not a valid integer");
    }
```